# When I'm using npm i @vertical-insure/web-components@4.1.2 package, after installed when I'm importing getting loader error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js, loader

This is error:

```
./node_modules/lit-html/directives/class-map.js 6:106
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:106)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|  * Copyright 2018 Google LLC
|  * SPDX-License-Identifier: BSD-3-Clause
>  */const e=s(class extends i{constructor(t){if(super(t),t.type!==r.ATTRIBUTE||"class"!==t.name||t.strings?.length>2)throw Error("`classMap()` can only be used in the `class` attribute and must be the only part in the attribute.")}render(t){return" "+Object.keys(t).filter((s=>t[s])).join(" ")+" "}update(s,[i]){if(void 0===this.st){this.st=new Set,void 0!==s.strings&&(this.nt=new Set(s.strings.join(" ").split(/\s/).filter((t=>""!==t))));for(const t in i)i[t]&&!this.nt?.has(t)&&this.st.add(t);return this.render(i)}const r=s.element.classList;for(const t of this.st)t in i||(r.remove(t),this.st.delete(t));for(const t in i){const s=!!i[t];s===this.st.has(t)||this.nt?.has(t)||(s?(r.add(t),this.st.add(t)):(r.remove(t),this.st.delete(t)))}return t}});export{e as classMap};
| //# sourceMappingURL=class-map.js.map
```

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "kaleidoscope-fe",
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.x",
    "npm": "6.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "analyze": "cross-env ANALYZE=true next build",
    "start": "NODE_OPTIONS='-r @newrelic/next' NODE_ENV=production node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/storage-blob": "^12.16.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-do-expressions": "^7.14.0",
    "@mars/heroku-js-runtime-env": "^3.0.2",
    "@newrelic/next": "^0.4.0",
    "@next/bundle-analyzer": "^11.1.2",
    "@sentry/nextjs": "^7.80.1",
    "@sentry/react": "^7.80.1",
    "@sentry/tracing": "^7.80.1",
    "@sentry/webpack-plugin": "^1.20.0",
    "@vertical-insure/web-components": "^4.1.0",
    "@zeit/next-css": "^1.0.1",
    "@zeit/next-sass": "^1.0.1",
    "antd": "^4.16.2",
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "body-scroll-lock": "^3.1.5",
    "chart.js": "^3.5.1",
    "cleave.js": "^1.6.0",
    "countries-states-cities": "^1.0.6",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "csurf": "^1.11.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "dropbox": "^9.4.0",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "he": "^1.2.0",
    "isomorphic-unfetch": "^3.1.0",
    "js-file-download": "^0.4.12",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "luxon": "^1.28.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "new-relic-agent-react": "^2.0.1",
    "newrelic": "^9.11.0",
    "next": "^10.0.8",
    "next-cookies": "^2.0.3",
    "next-redux-wrapper": "^6.0.2",
    "next-strict-csp": "^1.0.1",
    "nextjs-cors": "^2.1.2",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "npm": "^6.14.17",
    "postcss": "^8.4.32",
    "prismic-dom": "^2.1.0",
    "prismic-javascript": "^2.2.0",
    "prismic-reactjs": "^1.2.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "puppeteer": "^15.0.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-actioncable-provider": "^2.0.0",
    "react-autosuggest": "^10.1.0",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.0.0",
    "react-bootstrap-sweetalert": "^5.2.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^3.0.4",
    "react-content-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "react-datepicker": "^3.3.0",
    "react-doc-viewer": "^0.1.5",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-google-login": "^5.2.2",
    "react-gtm-module": "^2.0.11",
    "react-idle-timer": "^4.6.4",
    "react-mentions": "^4.1.1",
    "react-phone-input-2": "^2.13.9",
    "react-places-autocomplete": "^7.3.0",
    "react-player": "^2.9.0",
    "react-quill": "^1.3.5",
    "react-range": "^1.8.9",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.3",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-select": "^3.1.1",
    "react-share": "^4.4.0",
    "react-signature-canvas": "^1.0.5",
    "react-slick": "^0.28.1",
    "react-stripe-elements": "^6.1.2",
    "react-table": "^7.6.1",
    "react-table-hoc-fixed-columns": "^2.3.3",
    "react-timeago": "^5.2.0",
    "react-toastify": "^6.2.0",
    "recharts": "^2.10.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "sanitize-html": "^2.7.3",
    "slugify": "^1.4.7",
    "swiper": "^6.8.4",
    "throttle-debounce": "^3.0.1",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "winston": "^3.8.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-assertions": "^7.12.1",
    "browserslist": ">=4.16.5",
    "glob-parent": ">=5.1.2",
    "object-path": ">=0.11.5",
    "trim-newlines": ">=3.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0"
  }
}
```